# How to describe the pitch of someone’s voice

Tags: word-meaning

During a discussion on Telegram, someone wanted to say that they have a high-pitched voice. They used a phrase like this:

> Mia voĉo havas altan piĉon

At first I thought this was just an amusing mistake and they had gotten confused by a word that sounds like the English word. However, I now notice that PIV actually has this meaning as the second definition of the word:

> **piĉ/o** Tonalto: *teni, levi la piĉon; ĥoro senakompana ofte perdas la piĉon k kantas subpiĉe.*

Is this really the right word to use in this context? It seems pretty surprising that this meaning is used alongside the main meaning, considering that the latter is intended to be vulgar.

[John Well’s dictionary](https://www.smashwords.com/books/view/508176) simply suggests *tonalto* and [ReVo](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/picx.html) doesn’t have this second meaning for *piĉo*.

So the question is, does this second meaning really exist? Or is it just a curiosity in PIV? Is there any reason not to prefer a different way of saying it, like one of the following?

> - Mia voĉo havas altan tonon
> - Mia voĉo estas alta
> - Mia voĉo havas altan tonalton.

Comment: PIV even has the word "pitĉo" as a synonym for "piĉo". But both words are hardly ever used with this meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En sia *Alfabeta terminaro* de *Roko kaj Popo* Bertilo taksas la vortojn *piĉo* kaj *pitĉo* evitindaj, kaj rekomendas la vorton *tonalto* por tia senco. Jen listo de tradukoj laŭ diversaj sencoj de la angla *pitch*:

> perfect pitch = absoluta tonsento
>
> pitch = tonalto
>
> pitchbend = tonfleksado
>
> pitchbend control = tonfleksilo
>
> pitch control = tonaltoregilo

La retejo [Roko kaj Popo](https://bertilow.com/roko/index.html) estas tre interesa por esperanto-parolantoj kiuj ŝatas muzikon, aparte se ili estas muzikistoj. En ĝi oni trovos multajn tradukojn el anglaj muzik-terminoj, ĉar, kiel Bertilo diras, *en roko, popo kaj ĵazo plej multaj internaciaj vortoj estas Angladevenaj*.

En Tekstaro aperas eĉ ne unu trafo de la vorto *piĉo* kun la senco de *tonalto*.

Miaopinie, oni rajtas uzi la vorton *piĉo* en la senco de *tonalto*. Oni tamen sciu, ke tia uzo estas maloftega, evitinda kaj konfuziga. La plej evidentaj kialoj uzi ĝin estas deziro esti ambigua (ekz. ŝerce) aŭ nescio pri la reala lingvouzo.

Answer (score 0):

Se temas pri voĉo en Telegram, mi uzus *akuta*:

```
akuta - (pp sono) havanta altajn frekvencojn: akuta voĉo de knabino
```

Comment: Mi devis kontroli de PIV, ĉu vere la vorto _akuta_ havas tiun sencon, ĉar mi aŭtomate asocias la vorton kun "akuta krizo" aŭ "akuta malsano". Vi pravas, sed "akuta voĉo" sonas strange.

Comment: Jes, mi komprenas, kion oni ne kutimas uzi aŭ ne antaŭe konis/aŭdis, tio sonas strange, unue almenaŭ. Ankaŭ la angla uzas _acute_ por voĉoj, kaj la franca kaj hispana. Ĉiuokaze, tio aperas kelkfoje (akutaj voĉoj/krioj) en Tekstaro.